# How can I make a program change tasks based on voice recognition?

Tags: python, voice-recognition

I'm totally new to programming, maybe my problem is newbie, but I know a little bit of python. I'm trying to build robot kind of machine to do some specific work, but I want him also to answer my "hi", so I mean machines will go through code step by step and do as it say (work I going to give him) so do I need to specify after like every two line

```
if input_voice == "hi":
    print hi
```

Basically I want to know how can we detect voices and reply and middle of the work, the code to do specific work, 
Sorry if you don't understand, I'm very bad at explaining

Comment: I suggest you try learning more about the language basics before trying to build voice recognition, which is far from straightforward. Your minimal example doesn't use python syntax.

Comment: The technology is called *speech recognition*, and if you're *totally new to programming*, you're in no way ready to even think about using it. Learn to crawl before you try to run in a triathlon.

Comment: Are you on mac?